# C++ new() crashing before calling ctor

Tags: c++, constructor, new-operator, segmentation-fault

thank you for looking at my problem.

I have an object that is being dynamically created in my program. The creation is part of a loop and the first iteration works fine.

Upon creation, my object base class adds itself to a map.

Here is some sample code :

```
public class Base {  
    Base() {
        // Add itself to a map
        Data::objects[key] = this;
    }
}

public class Derived : public Base {
    // This ctor only initialize one int field.
    Derived() : Base() {};
}
```

Kinda simple isn't it ?

In my code, I do `Derived * d = new Derived();` and for some silly reason, I get a SIGSEGV.

I tried to debug it, but **it doesn't even enters the ctor before crashing!**

Here is my call stack so you can help me better:

Address: @0x002c0000
ntdll!RtlReleasePebLock()
Address: @0x0000000c at c:...\stl_deque.h:514
msvrct!malloc()
libstdc++-6!_Znwj()
*fu87*_ZSt4cerr(this=0xbc1ad8, e="//my object name//") at //my object name//.cpp
... Other are my lines.

Thank you, Micael

{enjoy}

Edit: Adding informations about the map

The map is located in a data class, statically.

```
// Data.h
class Data {
    static map<int, Base*> objects;
}

// Data.cpp
#include "Data.h"
map<int, Base*> Data::objects;

// methods implementations
```

How can you corrupt the heap, how can I find a corruption has occured?

Comment: Where is `map` defined? This sort of issue tends to indicate that you've already corrupted the heap; unfortunately, this sort of problem may not manifest itself until long after it occurs. The issue might be somewhere completely unrelated in your code.  Can you put together a relatively small sample program that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: By the way, the correct term is `Derived`, not `Derivated` ;-)

Comment: did you remove an unused function or variable from an header? Did you try to clean and rebuild?

Comment: Not enough information. How where and what is map.

Comment: @FredOverflow: thank you, I'm not an english speaker.

Comment: Please reduce the problem to a small test-case.  From the evidence in existence at this moment, the fragments don't even compile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Has `Data::objects` been initialized prior to the creation of ANY of the usages of `Base`?

You are not guaranteed that the class object `objects` had been initialized whenever you have more than one translation unit (read, `.cpp` file) in the final link target, unless you've gone to special effort to ensure it.

Most people solve this problem by using a static class through which this initialization is guaranteed to have occurred on first use.  Something like:

```
// untested code, typed in by hand, not compiled through a machine compiler.
class Base {
    public: static addObject(Base* that);
    Base::Base() { Base::addObject(this); }
};
class Derived: public Base {
    Derived::Derived() {}
};
//
// and in the .CPP for Base
namespace /* hidden */ {
    int object_number = 0;
    map<int,Base*> *objects = NULL;
}
void Base::addObject(Base* that) {
    // TODO: do something to avoid multi-thread issues if that is ever a concern
    if (!objects) {
        objects = new map<int,Base*>();
    }
    (*objects)[++object_number] = that;
}
```

Comment: That is a good observation, however the map is not a pointer type, and is initialized in the .cpp file.

Comment: Although it should have been initialized (AFAIK it should do it automatically), the error disappeared. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: Just because it is initialized in the .cpp file, does not mean that it is initialized before the *first* object is created that happens to use it.

Answer (score 2):

You've probably corrupted the heap at some point prior to the allocation, which causes the crash.  Try running with [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) to see where you're going wrong

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm working on a Windows 7 environment, I can't use Valgrind since it only works on Linux. Is that my only option ? Should I use a virtual machine to run it ?

Comment: Virtual machine? Good Heavens! Just post the code that causes the problem. All of it (but as small as you can make it).